# Creating Lookalike Audiences via Facebook Graph API in-browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

First, I think it's important to note that I'm NOT a developer - I'm a social media marketer that's trying to begin the very basics of the FB Marketing API.

In short, I've successfully used the graph API to pull data from the FB API using the /insights parameter for any number of accounts/campaigns/ad sets, etc... and it works great.

GET commands in general are a cakewalk.  What I'm having difficulty with now are POST commands - specifically trying to create a new Lookalike list from an existing custom audience.  All my API calls are being conducted in Chrome.

Here's what my call looks like:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_***AD_ACCOUNT_ID***/customaudiences/?access_token=***MY_TOKEN***&lookalike_spec=%7B%27type%27%3A+%27similarity%27%2C+%27country%27%2C+%27DE%27%7D&origin_audience_id=***MY_AUDIENCE_ID***&name=TESTLAL&subtype=LOOKALIKE
```

When I send this call, all it returns is a full list of audience IDs for the given account - no lookalike has been made.

Any help on this would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform direct POST commands from the browser. Instead, I would advise to

1. Learn the command-line [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) tool. It requires a bit of learning, but once mastered is very easy to use and you can easily save your requests in a document, and re-use later.
2. Use the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me). Here it's easy to create POST calls, but it's a bit harder to save them to re-use later on.

Answer (score 0):

@Roemer thats actually incorrect.  I figured it out in the end.

My API call was correct, the only parameter I needed to add at the end of the URL was &method=POST and it created the lists no problem.